# i have Imported installed quill but the issue with user interface

Tags: quil, ngx-quill

Well I followed the example 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sh3_k_QPGzw

I don't get the Quill tool bar as shown in the any of the examples[image: the image attached is the User interface i get after the quill implementation]

```
<div style="text-align:center">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row pt-5">
<div class="col-md-8">

<form [formGroup]="editorForm" (ngsubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="editor"><h3>editor</h3></label>
      <quill-editor></quill-editor>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like you are missing the styles - see my answer below..

Comment: Did my suggestion to import the styles work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried your example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="editor"><h3>editor</h3></label>
    <quill-editor></quill-editor>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

It works fine showing all the standard toolbar-items, so make sure you also imported `quill.snow.css` and `quill.bubble.css`

```
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in your html and

```
@import "./app/quill/quill-emoji.css";
@import "./app/quill/quill-mention.css";
```

in your `styles.css`.

If you are using your own custom toolbar container you also need to create the buttons inside it.

From the official docs:

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: {
      container: '#toolbar',  // Selector for toolbar container
      handlers: {
        'bold': customBoldHandler
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Because the container option is so common, a top level shorthand is also allowed.

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    // Equivalent to { toolbar: { container: '#toolbar' }}
    toolbar: '#toolbar'
  }
});
```

The official documentation and some good examples:

- [Doc on toolbar](http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/)
- [Example](http://quilljs.com/standalone/full/)
- [Example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-quill)
- [Example on CodePen with custom toolbar-container](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLzmXo)

Comment: @CoderBackEndDev Great that you got it working - if my answer helped you and might help others in the future, feel free to [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it ;)

Comment: @iLovLogix i dont have enough reputaion to upvote  :-)

Comment: @CoderBackEndDev Now you have - I helped (upvoted) you a bit ;)